# How to enable a preference in my android application when other preference is disabled?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have used `PreferenceActivity` to have preference in my android application. I want one preference say "pref 2" to be enabled when other preference say "pref 1" is NOT checked and "pref 2" to be disabled when "pref 1" is checked. 
i.e.  exactly opposite of the `android:dependancy` attribute.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think there's any out-of-the-box solution for it, i.e. an inverted `dependancy` attribute. But there's always the click-listener:

```
preference1.setOnPreferenceClickListener(pref1_click);

....

private OnPreferenceClickListener pref1_click = new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        preference2.setEnabled(!preference1.isChecked());
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 97):

Yes it's possible to do this out of the box.
Let's say you want to disable pref2 when pref1 is off
Here's the code(preference xml layout) to put in for pref1:

```
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:title="Pref1"
    android:key="pref1">
</CheckBoxPreference>
```

Here's the code(preference xml layout) to put in for pref2:

```
<EditTextPreference
    android:dialogMessage="Pref 2 dialog"
    android:title="Pref2"
    android:key="pref2" 
    android:dependency="pref1">
</EditTextPreference>
```

Like sigmazero13 said, by default disableDependentsState is false so you don't need to include it in the pref1 attributes.

Comment: For me it was better to do this sort of thing in XML

Comment: What if these preferences are on different xml layouts?

Comment: @Maxrunner I use strings (in the strings.xml file) as my key names.  This way, you can reference the key in your code, and other xml files.  That should work.

Answer (score 31):

According to the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/CheckBoxPreference.html#attr_android:disableDependentsState), you can add an attribute to the CheckBoxPreference tag like so:

```
android:disableDependentsState="true"
```

By default this is false, which means that the dependents are disabled when the checkbox is unchecked, but by setting it to true, it should have the opposite effect.

Comment: Tested it myself and this does exactly what OP requested, all within the XML =].

Comment: The attribute has to be added to the preference which others depend on, not on the dependent preference. Imho it would have been better if the choice had been done by the dependent preference... what if two dependent preferences need to behave different according to the value of another preference? anyway...

Answer (score 0):

### Android CheckBox??

---

I am assuming you are using the Android.widget.checkBox:

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html

Try this

```
 public class MyActivity extends Activity {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
         super.onCreate(icicle);

         setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);

         final CheckBox checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_id);
         if (checkBox1.isChecked()) {
             checkBox2.setChecked(false);
         }
     }
 }
```

GoodLUCK!!

Comment: No I am using android.preference.CheckBoxPreference NOT Android.widget.checkBox. AnyWay Thanks for your concern.