# Android CheckBoxPreference: how to disable and enable other preferences on preference change

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have CheckBoxPreference and 2 others: one is Edit Test Pref. and another is ListBox Pref. How I can **enable** list box pref and **disable** edit text pref. when CheckBoxPreference  is turned on?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Seems it's duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672922/how-to-enable-a-preference-in-my-android-application-when-other-preference-is-dis)

You can override `public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, final String key)` and when it get called with `key.equals(<Your key for setting>)` do something like:

```
boolean isEnabled = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, true);
getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("list box preference key").setEnabled(isEnabled);
getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("list box preference key").setEnabled(!isEnabled);
```

Also, do the same in `onCreate()` to have Your preferences screen proper initial setup.

Answer (score 37):

As a variant, it's possible to put the "dependency" into the ListBoxPref.

```
<PreferenceCategory
android:key="key1"
android:title="@string/title1">
<SwitchPreference
    android:key="parents"
    android:summaryOff="@string/do_smthng"
    android:summaryOn="@string/do_smthng"
    android:switchTextOff="@string/i_am_sleeping"
    android:switchTextOn="@string/i_have_free_time" />
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="baby"
    android:dependency="parents"
    android:title="@string/basic_habbits"
    android:summaryOff="@string/play_with_parents"
    android:summaryOn="@string/play_with_parents"
    android:defaultValue="true" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

Basically, baby can't play with parents when they are sleeping =)

Comment: You are awesome sir!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for... I had disabled the use in my code, but needed to show the user that they are disabled so they can turn it on.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the checkbox value. And then, to enable/disable the preferences, you can use    `pref.setEnabled(false);` To enable, just use the same function and put the true value.

Answer (score 3):

Just to simplify the answer from Sergio,

```
  android:dependency="keyOfParent"
```

This makes the item dependent on the parent item, may need to be a switch.

Also adding a listener to the onSharedPreferenceChanged works, sometimes.. it sometimes doesn't work as desired ( not sure why )

Add

```
public class YourClass extends Whatever implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
```

Then after OnCreate()

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged (SharedPreferences p1, String p2)
     {      
     if (Your Arguments)
      {
        // getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("pref_key").setEnabled(false);
      }
     }
```